# How to align the content of a RelativeLayout to the right of an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create an item_view layout to inflate in a ListView, which appears as shown at the following link: [Layout example](http://oi60.tinypic.com/ohvcav.jpg).

The main RelativeLayout contains an ImageView and another RelativeLayout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/outbox_message_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_favorite" />
```

On the right of the ImageView I have this RelativeLayout which contains the two textField:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/outbox_message_info_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/outbox_message_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/outbox_message_icon" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="TextView1" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/separator" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="TextView2" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

but I obtain this result: [layout results](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2571wt4.jpg).
I have no idea why I obtain the correct result. Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LinearLayout` for your `TextViews` and divider as bellow. Just change back the image to your image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/outbox_message_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/outbox_message_info_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/outbox_message_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/outbox_message_icon" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#000000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result:
[image: Preview]